# Using Identify in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, pixel, extract-by-mask, identify

I am a fresh to GIS.

In ArcMap 10.3 I can use the Identify tool to check the same pixel in time series, but in ArcGIS Pro when I load several rasters, it can only identify one layer.

What can I do so that I can identify the same pixel in a time series in ArcGIS Pro?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To help orient ArcMap users to using ArcGIS Pro, Esri has provided [FAQ: Is the Identify tool available in ArcGIS Pro?](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012907) which starts:

> By default, there is no Identify tool in ArcGIS Pro. The default tool
> for all views in ArcGIS Pro is the Explore tool. For more details,
> refer to ArcGIS Pro Help page, [Navigation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/navigation/navigation-in-arcgis-pro.htm).
>
> In addition, if another tool is active, selected, or measuring,
> holding down the 'C' key temporarily activates the Explore tool to
> easily pan, zoom, or identify, without having to change the tool.
> Currently, it is not possible to draw a box to identify features with
> the Explore tool.